# Google Sign-in Java client payload attributes

Tags: java, google-signin

This is the first time I am going to criticize Google.

I don´t know if I am missing something or I am a bit stupid but when you want to know about Google API´s and check what suits your app needs better, it gets really messy and hard to understand. I mean the documentation is quite badly organized. You just don´t know what to ready or if you are learning the right approach.

In the case of the Java client for Google Sign-in, when I get the GoogleIdToken.Payload object after verifying the token, looking at the API it seems that I just can get the e-mail address (apart from other info that is not really useful for me). For example, I wanted to get the name of the user and picture.

I thought that this info was missing but when I debugged the application I realized that the GoogleIdToken.Payload object actually holds this information. It can be found in the map in GenericData class, which is a class that GoogleIdToken.Payload extends from. The map keys are "name" and "picture".
I got a bit annoyed because I cannot find this info anywhere. Not in the Java docs, not in the documentation. **Is this really the way I have to follow to look for user info?**

The documentation is really poor...

Comment: Okay, but that is not a question - that's a rant. That's not what SO is for.

Comment: The question is there:  "Is this really the way I have to follow to look for user info?"

Comment: I don't see it, there is still too much rant around it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Well, I think I did fine: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."